# Creating new pairs based on existing pairs and their relationships

Tags: python

I am working on a dataset with 2 million pairs which are arranged like this.

```
pair_relation    item1_id    item2_id
1                100         101
1                101         102
1                102         103
0                103         104
```

Here `pair_relation` shows equality relation between `item1` and `item2` in binary form. Now I want to generate new pairs based on existing information in a way that if `item100` is equal to `item101` and `item101` is equal to `item102` and `item102` is equal to `item103` but `item103` is not equal to `item104` , it means `item104` is also not equal to `item102`, `item101` and `item100`.

```
pair_relation    item1_id    item2_id
1                100         101
1                101         102
1                102         103
0                103         104
0                102         104
0                101         104
0                100         104
```

In short it's a way of saying if `A` equals `B` and B not_equals `C` then `A` is also not_equals `C`. I have implemented a naive code in python involving three loops. It takes hours to run and sometimes goes out of memory and crashes. In Python, there must be an efficient and sophisticated way to achieve that.

Comment: Is the data guaranteed not to contain contradictory information wrt to the given constraints?

Comment: what kind of format is the data stored as? `csv` file or some other?

Comment: Data is in csv format (comma as delimiter). And it is no guarantee that there are no contradictory information. If there is some contradictory pairs, it should be marked separately so that human judge can review it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your file is a csv :

```
related={}
unrelated={}
new_rel={}

f=open('filename.csv')

line=f.readline()
while line:      #iterate until EOF is reached 
    l=line.split(',').rstrip()   #split through comma and remove newline character
    if int(l[0]) == 1:  # if pair relation is 1
            if l[1] not in related.keys():  #if key is not present
                 related[int(l[1])]=[]           #generate key which contains a list
            related[int(l[1])].append(int(l[2])) #append number to list
    else :   # if pair relation is 1
       if l[1] not in unrelated.keys():
          unrelated[int(l[1])]=[]
       unrelated[int(l[1])].append(int(l[2]))
    line=f.readline()                 #read next line
f.close()
```

It will return a dictionary **related** where each **key** contains a list of numbers that are **equal to the key** similarly **unrelated** is also a dictionary for **not equal key**.

```
for k in unrelated.keys(): #for each key in unrelated
    for vals in unrelated[k]:  #for each value of list at key-k
        if vals not in new_rel.keys():
            new_rel[vals]=[]
        new_rel[vals] += related[k]
```

**EXAMPLE**: 
 if **unrelated** contains `{100:[102,103],500:[102]}`, then **new_rel** will contain `{102:[related of 100 + related of 500], 103:[related of 100]}`

**FINALLY**:

```
for k in new_rel.keys():  #to eliminate duplicates
    eliminate_duplicate=set(new_rel[k])
    new_rel[k]=eliminate_duplicate
```

Since I don't have any data to test I can't be sure of this, the code may be *buggy*. Feel free to correct it.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. I have made this dictionary using your code. It is way faster than my implementation. Problem is, I am not familiar with python much. I am having trouble to check the relationship and then form new pairs. If you can help me with that, I would be much obliged. I have made dictionary of all 1s. I have made dictionary of all 0s. How to make new pairs with efficient coding?